# SonarQube 6.7 using Sonar Auth Github 1.3 Plugin

Tags: authentication, github, sonarqube, single-sign-on

I am trying to use SonarQube with Github as authentication.

- Here it shows the plugin is [compatible](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix)
- I've followed the [instructions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Authentication+Plugin) to setup the plugin

When I try to authenticate I get this error in the log

> [o.s.s.a.AuthenticationError] No provider key found in URI

Then I am redirected to

> "GET /sessions/unauthorized HTTP/1.0" 200

I found in the SonarQube [code](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/server/sonar-server/src/main/java/org/sonar/server/authentication/AuthenticationFilter.java#L52) where the error is thrown.

This is the source for the [Github Sonar Auth Extension](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-auth-github)

How does one place a provider key in the URI?

Comment: Could you please check in SonarQube settings that the "Authorization callback URL" is correctly set to something like "http://localhost:9000/oauth2/callback" ?

Comment: Yes it was set. I am using Nginx in front of SonarQube however. I actually got it working by checking out the SonarQube source code and modifying it.

Comment: What did you change ?

Comment: A hacky solution, but if the providerKey = null then set it to equal to 'github' on this line https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/server/sonar-server/src/main/java/org/sonar/server/authentication/AuthenticationFilter.java#L52

Comment: This issue is very strange. I suspect an issue with the Nginx configuration as this issue has never been reported elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Please note the GitHub auth plugin requirements (from Configuration -> General Settings -> GitHub)

> - SonarQube must be publicly accessible through HTTPS only
> - The property 'sonar.core.serverBaseURL' must be set to this public HTTPS URL
> - In your GitHub profile, you need to create a Developer Application for
>     which the 'Authorization callback URL' must be set to '/oauth2/callback'.

In my case, I wase experiencing the same error (No provider key found in URI), and setting sonar.core.serverBaseURL in my sonar.properties fixed the problem

Comment: Yes I followed these instructions twice and never got it working right. I had another co-worker even try to set it up so make sure I wasn't missing something and he had the same problem.